# How to run Azure Data Factory pipeline on Java Eclipse

Tags: java, azure, azure-data-factory, bdd

I am doing a project to integrate ADF pipeline with Java project. Is there any possible way to run the ADF pipeline remotely using Java?

I am a newcomer to this field and I didn't find any valuable articles regarding the question. Pls let me know if there is any possible solution to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the REST API to trigger pipeline runs from external applications, including Java. It is a POST request, and you may find details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?tabs=HTTP

Alternatively, there is a Data Factory client library for Java. It appears to be in beta, but provides the functionality you are looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/resourcemanager-datafactory-readme?view=azure-java-preview